# Find nth Fibonacci number in O(1) time complexity

Tags: algorithm, math

I want to find the nth Fibonacci number in **O(1) time complexity**.I know about the golden ratio technique, but this fails for very large input. Is there any other way to find it?

Comment: Ridiculous closure. Voting to re-open.

Comment: This would probably be better on http://math.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: @EJP this is not ridiculous closure. The question violates several SO rules: no attempt to solve it by OP, no research done (just here is my question - do it now). Question is extremely simple and just a wikipeadia article gives you enough to solve it.

Comment: What do you need it for? Depending on your application you might be able to work with it in exponential form or algebraically bypassing the actual exponentiation. Although, odds are it won't be possible to bypass it completely, but it may still be useful. Again, depending on what you need it for.

Comment: actually I was developing my own algorithm for encrypting text. The procedure includes finding Fibonacci number. So I just wanted to reduce the complexity of my algorithm.

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to find Fibonacci number in `O(1)` time (without
   pre-processing).

Note that if you require the output to be the number, it requires `O(logN)` bits to encode it - and you are going to need to write them somehow - it will take at least `O(logN)` time to do it.

- The golden-ratio technique is also `O(logN)` because it requires
  exponent - you need to raise the golden ratio in a power of `n`.
  Exponent is `Omega(logN)` function - so this solution is also
  `O(logN)`, and as you noticed - it fails for large number, due to
  rounding errors, which get very large when raising with a large
  exponent.

An efficient alternative which runs in `O(logN)` and is exact is the [matrix formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Matrix_form):
Raising the matrix :

```
1  1
1  0
```

in power of `n`, gives you:

```
F_(n+1)   F_n
F_n       F_(n-1)
```

Where `F_i` is the ith fibonacci number.

Comment: The remark about printing isn't relevant. The question is about finding, not printing.

Comment: The remark is relevant, because if you can't read something in O(1) time, you certainly can't compute it in that time.

Comment: ref: http://fusharblog.com/solving-linear-recurrence-for-programming-contest